# give a default value for an attribute if the value is null in json by jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

Suppose i have class i.e.

```
private class Student {
        private Integer x = 1000;

        public Integer getX() {
            return x;
        }

        public void setX(Integer x) {
            this.x = x;
        }
    }
```

Now suppose json is `"{x:12}"` and doing deserialization then the `x` will have the value is `12`. But if the json is  `"{}"` then the value of `x = 1000` (get is from the default value of the attribute declared in the class).

Now if the json is  `"{x:null}"` then value of x becomes `null` but here even in this case i want  value of `x` to be `1000`. **How to do it via jackson**. Thanks in advance.

**I am deserializing via below method, if it helps in anyway:
`objectMapper.readValue(<json string goes here>, Student.class);`**

Comment: which unmarshalling method do you use: streaming, tree model or data binding?

Comment: @SergeyPauk `objectMapper.readValue(<json string goes here>, Student.class);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class Student {
    private Integer x = Integer.valueOf(1000);

    public Integer getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(Integer x) {
        if(x != null) {
           this.x = x;
        }
    }
}
```

This works for me........

**Test code 1:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String s = "{\"x\":null}";
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Student ss = mapper.readValue(s, Student.class);
        System.out.println(ss.getX());
    }
```

**output:**

`1000`

**Test code 2:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String s = "{}";
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Student ss = mapper.readValue(s, Student.class);
        System.out.println(ss.getX());
    }
```

**output:**

`1000`

Comment: that what i have proposed from the start but you have rejected it ... I really don't get you.

Comment: @SergeyPauk I downvoted your original post when you proposed a solution with `JsonDeserializer` which had typos and complicated life. The solution with the `if x == null` is not wrong.

Comment: @SergeyPauk For future reference, don't delete your answers and repost them. If they are correct, people will eventually upvote them. Don't stress about a single downvote or two.

Comment: @SergeyPauk actually i have given upvote to you by believing your words. you down voted me. why?

Comment: @Trying nope, no downvotes today. There's some prankster around I suppose. You could notice that all the answers were downvoted.

Comment: @Trying i would suggest that you close this topic by accepting on of the answers.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to override the setter. Add the `@JsonProperty(value="x")` annotations to the getter and setter to let Jackson know to use them:

```
private class Student {
    private static final Integer DEFAULT_X = 1000;
    private Integer x = DEFAULT_X;

    @JsonProperty(value="x")
    public Integer getX() {
        return x;
    }

    @JsonProperty(value="x")
    public void setX(Integer x) {
        this.x = x == null ? DEFAULT_X : x;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider extending [JsonDeserializer](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.3.1/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/JsonDeserializer.html)

custom deserializer:

```
public class StudentDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Student> {
    @Override
    public Student deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        JsonNode node = p.getCodec().readTree(p);
        // if JSON is "{}" or "{"x":null}" then create Student with default X
        if (node == null || node.get("x").isNull()) {
            return new Student();
        }
        // otherwise create Student with a parsed X value
        int x = (Integer) ((IntNode) node.get("x")).numberValue();
        Student student = new Student();
        student.setX(x);
        return student;
    }
}
```

and it's use:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addDeserializer(Student.class, new StudentDeserializer());
mapper.registerModule(module);     
Student readValue = mapper.readValue(<your json string goes here>", Student.class);
```

Comment: Without this if you write:

`public class Student {
        private Integer x = Integer.valueOf(1000);

        public Integer getX() {
            return x;
        }

        public void setX(Integer x) {
            if(x != null) {
               this.x = x;
            }
        }
    }`
This works. Why you want to go for a complex solution?

Comment: Sure, Student is supposed to be a public class in this case.

Comment: Yeah, although this is a "jackson solution", it's much more complex.

Comment: Because your requirement was also complex, i.e. two special cases `null` and `empty`

Comment: @Trying overriding the setter was my first proposal but you mentioned that you would like to do it via jackson so here it is.

Comment: @SergeyPauk if that is the thing then +1.

Answer (score 0):

From json to object, you could fix this in the setter and tell Jackson to not use Field access but use the setter for unmarshalling.

Comment: how to tell jackson to use setter?

Comment: @JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = Visibility.NONE, getterVisibility = Visibility.ALL, setterVisibility = Visibility.ALL)